# Value called from .cljc to .clj always null

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

My common.cljc file looks like this:

```
   (ns example.common
     #?(:cljs
    (:require [goog.dom :as gdom])
       )
    )

    #?(:cljs (enable-console-print!))

   (defn mobile? []
        #?(:cljs (def hvpsize (.. (gdom/getViewportSize) -height))) 
        #?(:cljs (def wvpsize (.. (gdom/getViewportSize) -width))) 
        #?(:cljs (if (<= (/ wvpsize hvpsize) 1) true false))
   )

   (def mobile-value (mobile?))

   (println "mobile-value inside .cljc")
   (println mobile-value)
```

My routes.clj file looks like this:

```
     (ns example.routes 
        (:gen-class)
        (:use compojure.core
               example.views
               example.common
               [hiccup.middleware :only (wrap-base-url)])
        )

        (use '[ring.util.response :only [response]])
        (use '[ring.adapter.jetty :only [run-jetty]])
        (require '[compojure.route :as route])

        (defn -main
          "I don't do a whole lot ... yet."
          [& args]
          (println "Hello, World!"))

        (defn d-or-m-version [] 
           (.println System/out "Inside d-or-m-version")
           (.println System/out mobile-value)
           (if mobile-value (root-page-mobile) (root-page-desktop))
           )

        (defroutes main-routes 
           (GET "/" [] (d-or-m-version))
           (route/not-found "404"))

        (defonce server (run-jetty #'main-routes {:port 8080 :join? false}))
```

`mobile-value` evaluates correctly when reloading the page in the .cljc file and even in a separate .cljs file I have.

The issue is when `mobile-value` is evaluated in routes.clj it just returns null. Hence the if statement in `d-or-v-version` does not call the correct hiccup html from a separate views.clj file.

I am assuming `mobile-value` is returning null because routes.clj is run before common.cljc while `mobile-value` has no value. However I have no idea how to resolve this, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It evaluates to `nil` when called from Clojure because it's an empty function in Clojure.  The `#?(:cljs` reader conditional tells the Clojure compiler to ignore this form because it is supposed to be evaluated by the Clojurescript compiler only.

Since all of the forms in that function don't exist to the Clojure compiler, the function is empty, and it will always evaluate to `nil`.

Comment: Ah makes sense and thank you for the response. Is there anyway I can capture that boolean value in `mobile?` in a way that the clojure compiler can evaluate it? Or perhaps another way to address the issue? 
The only way I seem to be able to tell if the user is on mobile or not is to use js libs through cljs but all my routes have to be in clj, so getting them to talk to each other seems like an unavoidable (but also common) problem.

Comment: I think you'd have to have the client tell the server if it's mobile or not. i.e. it's not a compile time concern for your server.

Comment: But when that client does have to eventually tell the server "Hey load this specific html/css for the root path page on mobile" how does one exchange that value from client to server without running into this issue? Sorry I may be misunderstanding something fundamental.

Comment: You could have the moble and desktop versions make requests on different urls, or send different parameters, or inspect browser headers, there are many ways to do it.